# ffmpeg mp4 x264 encoding -> playback causes "pending" in both Chrome and IE causing 10+ seconds delay

Tags: google-chrome, ffmpeg, html5-video

After encoding a video to mp4(x264 with aac);  I have the following weird behaviour in both crome and IE:

Im serving the content from https with spdy enables.

It takes up to 30 seconds before the video is actually played, in the mean time i cannot reload the page it shows up as "pending". (even after i have visual on the video sometimes it takes 10-20 seconds before i can actually reload the page, or navigate to another url on the same domain)

After looking at the "network" tab in developer tools, i see the following requests for 1 page/video:

```
Path        Method Status   Type         Initiator   Size/content  Time/latency
video.mp4   GET    206 OK   video/mp4    other       32.3KB/32.0kb  600ms/339MS 
video.mp4   GET    206 OK   video/mp4    other       123kb/123b     21.85s/21.46s
video.mp4   GET    206 OK   video/mp4    other       7.1MB/7.2MB    1.4min/2ms
```

I tried to isolate the problem, When i use an mp4 video from the internet (for example the demo video of jplayer) and load it from my server, it loads rapidly, without delays.

So it makes me think the problem lies within the encoding. I tried various things.
FFmpeg:

- csr 69 (low quality)
- various options

HTML:

- preload="none"
- javascript loading/playing of the movie
- type='mp4/video'
- no posterimage

But i cannot resolve the problem. Does anyone have a clue what is causing this?

I have a download speed of 300kb/s and the movie is 6MB.

After the video starts, the video isn't fully buffered, so i wonder: What is the html5 videoplayer doing all this time?

The problem also blocks the connections. When i press "F5" in both chrome and IE the page beeing reloaded comes up in the network tab as "pending" and it can take 10 to 20 seconds before the page actually reloads.

ffmpeg command: (i used various commands but this is just 1 example which causes the problem)

```
/root/bin/ffmpeg    -threads 1 -y  -i /home/flirtzo/public_html//userfiles/files/94e76a18a7838e62ecb23cf0c374b1b798e7b936  -threads 0 -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k  -vf "scale=-2:320" -preset veryslow -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2  /home/flirtzo/public_html/userfiles/files/b2/72/695f4eba95169a3f29564bf9571c703b05f1b5974f5156da633eb139c80a1575452e2858dfc61cc82bfca02d2b156aa64d4503695756481dc2a5d1c673a4cdea-94e76a18a7838e62ecb23cf0c374b1b798e7b936.mp4
```

Output:

```
ffmpeg version git-2014-04-16-c150e2c Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Sep 28 2014 21:08:17 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-        ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree -    -enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-    libx264
  libavutil      52. 76.100 / 52. 76.100
  libavcodec     55. 58.103 / 55. 58.103
  libavformat    55. 37.100 / 55. 37.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.100 / 55. 13.100
  libavfilter     4.  4.100 /  4.  4.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mpeg, from         '/home/flirtzo/public_html//userfiles/files/94e76a18a7838e62ecb23cf0c374b1b798e7b936':
  Duration: 00:00:25.97, start: 0.340078, bitrate: 29004 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv), 352x240 [SAR 200:219 DAR 880:657], 1150     kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 224 kb/s
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] using SAR=1199/1314
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] profile High, level 1.3
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] 264 - core 142 r2 d6b4e63 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 -     http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=2 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex     subme=4 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0     deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0     decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0     direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0     rc_lookahead=20 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=51.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to     '/home/flirtzo/public_html/userfiles/files/b2/72/695f4eba95169a3f29564bf9571c703b05f1b5974f5156da633e    b139c80a1575452e2858dfc61cc82bfca02d2b156aa64d4503695756481dc2a5d1c673a4cdea-    94e76a18a7838e62ecb23cf0c374b1b798e7b936.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.37.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 320x218 [SAR 1199:1314        DAR 880:657], q=-1--1, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg1video -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp2 -> aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=16127 fps=786 q=-1.0 Lsize=   10559kB time=00:08:58.12 bitrate= 160.7kbits/s dup=12 drop=0
video:1586kB audio:8410kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:     5.638589%
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] frame I:109   Avg QP:50.58  size:   494
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] frame P:9537  Avg QP:51.00  size:   138
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] frame B:6481  Avg QP:51.00  size:    40
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] consecutive B-frames: 21.8% 72.1%  5.4%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] mb I  I16..4: 46.1% 53.9%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] mb P  I16..4:  6.0%  6.1%  0.0%  P16..4: 12.7%  1.1%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%        skip:74.1%
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8:  6.3%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.7%      skip:92.9%  L0:38.6% L1:61.2% BI: 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] 8x8 transform intra:50.8% inter:85.6%
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 5.9% 39.5% 0.1% inter: 0.1% 1.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 56% 30%  7%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 12% 11% 62%  3%  3%  3%  3%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19%  5% 73%  2%  0%  0%  0%  0%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 97%  1%  2%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:5.5% UV:2.7%
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] ref P L0: 64.8% 35.2%
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] ref B L0: 75.2% 24.8%
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] ref B L1: 99.3%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x2b189c0] kb/s:24.13
ffmpeg version git-2014-04-16-c150e2c Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Sep 28 2014 21:08:17 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-    ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree -    -enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-    libx264
  libavutil      52. 76.100 / 52. 76.100
  libavcodec     55. 58.103 / 55. 58.103
  libavformat    55. 37.100 / 55. 37.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.100 / 55. 13.100
  libavfilter     4.  4.100 /  4.  4.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mpeg, from     '/home/flirtzo/public_html//userfiles/files/94e76a18a7838e62ecb23cf0c374b1b798e7b936':
  Duration: 00:00:25.97, start: 0.340078, bitrate: 29004 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv), 352x240 [SAR 200:219 DAR 880:657], 1150         kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 224 kb/s
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] using SAR=200/219
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] profile High, level 2.2
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] 264 - core 142 r2 d6b4e63 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 -                     http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=16 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x133 me=umh         subme=10 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=24 chroma_me=1 trellis=2 8x8dct=1 cqm=0     deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0     decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=8 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=2 b_bias=0     direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0     rc_lookahead=60 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to     '/home/flirtzo/public_html/userfiles/files/b2/72/73d4a3245c0b0e174ab7ce0f872ba3f649f8b93f73a6deeab364    4a994009d73638ce61aecc7dc2e0250c4e74ff2d9a4d479ed35cef26b3f6e1a77e8bf5938518-    94e76a18a7838e62ecb23cf0c374b1b798e7b936.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.37.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 352x240 [SAR 200:219     DAR 880:657], q=-1--1, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg1video -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp2 -> aac)
   Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=16127 fps= 88 q=-1.0 Lsize=   29190kB time=00:08:58.12 bitrate= 444.4kbits/s dup=12 drop=0
video:20221kB audio:8410kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:     1.954086%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] frame I:73    Avg QP:24.31  size:  8024
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] frame P:4399  Avg QP:26.97  size:  2600
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] frame B:11655 Avg QP:32.51  size:   745
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] consecutive B-frames:  3.8%  5.0% 27.2% 18.4%  8.4% 33.9%  1.7%  0.7%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] mb I  I16..4: 10.8% 68.5% 20.7%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] mb P  I16..4:  2.9%  7.5%  0.8%  P16..4: 45.1% 18.4% 12.4%  0.5%  0.1%        skip:12.3%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.6%  1.3%  0.1%  B16..8: 40.1%  8.7%  1.7%  direct: 2.1%      skip:45.5%  L0:47.2% L1:41.7% BI:11.1%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] 8x8 transform intra:66.7% inter:76.7%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] direct mvs  spatial:99.9% temporal:0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 60.3% 75.8% 16.4% inter: 17.3% 16.8% 0.6%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 16% 27% 11% 47%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 13% 13% 18%  6%  9%  9% 11%  9% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 13% 15%  7%  7% 14% 14% 13%  8% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 26% 32% 20% 22%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:10.1% UV:6.9%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] ref P L0: 40.6% 12.1% 10.0%  5.2%  5.2%  4.7%  4.6%  3.0%  2.5%  2.1%  1.9%      1.8%  1.7%  1.7%  1.6%  1.3%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] ref B L0: 71.4%  5.6%  3.2%  3.0%  3.1%  2.8%  2.5%  1.8%  1.3%  1.0%  1.1%      1.2%  1.0%  0.7%  0.5%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] ref B L1: 96.3%  3.7%
[libx264 @ 0x300d9c0] kb/s:307.82
```

Comment: What is your actual `ffmpeg` command and complete `ffmpeg` console output?

Comment: Added ffmpeg command and output to the post. Thank you for responding.

Comment: Does it work as expected if you add `-movflags +faststart` as an output option?

Comment: With the flags i still have the issues. I updated the post mentioning i am serving from https with spdy enabled, but i think i can excluded that problem because the jplayer demo movie loads perfectly fine. but i thought i mention it anyway.

Comment: It does seem to work now, it loads a lot quicker. Only problem i have left is, when i reload the page while the video is beeing loaded, the request says "pending" and the reload (or navigation to another url) is put on hold taking more than 10 seconds.

Comment: Hi, when i disable spdy, all problems are gone. So your answer is the correct solution to the ffmpeg problem. The spdy problem is another problem all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `-movflags +faststart` option. This will relocate the moov atom to the beginning of the file; otherwise the client will have to download the whole file before it can begin playback.

Users with a `ffmpeg` build that does not have this option are using something ancient and should refer to the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page (static builds are available that you can just download, extract, and execute).